# How to merge changes in a Git branch into 'trunk' of SVN by using Git only

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I want to checkout an SVN project, create a branch on remote SVN and the corresponding local Git branch. Then I want to do some changes. The changes should be reflected in both branches - SVN and Git as some people work in SVN and they should see the branch `task3`.

The script below does it successfully:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/tmp/svn-experiments # Directory for experiments
rm -rf "$DIR"
mkdir "$DIR"

cd $DIR
rm -rf svnrepos
svnadmin create svnrepos

# Create a project with standard SVN-project folder structure:
mkdir -p project/{trunk,branches,tags}
cd project/trunk/
echo "Hello" > readme.txt
echo "Log entry 1" > day.log

# Import the project into repository
svn import -m "Project import into repository" "$DIR"/project file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project

svn log file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project

# Simulate two users and conflict

# Developer 1 (svn) creates working copy, branch:
svn co file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project "$DIR"/developer_svn1

cd "$DIR"/developer_svn1

svn copy file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project/trunk file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project/branches/task1 -m "Create a branch for task 1" 

svn update

cd "$DIR"/developer_svn1/branches/task1

sed -i -r 's/(.*)/\1 world/g' readme.txt

svn commit -m "Change from developer_svn1"

svn update

# Developer 2 (svn) creates working copy, branch:
svn co file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project "$DIR"/developer_svn2

cd "$DIR"/developer_svn2

svn copy file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project/trunk file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project/branches/task2 -m "Create a branch for task 2" 

svn update

cd "$DIR"/developer_svn2/branches/task2

sed -i -r 's/(.*)/\1 Russia/g' readme.txt

svn commit -m "Change from developer_svn2"

svn update

# Currently creates a remote SVN branch 'task3' and the corresponding local Git branch 'task3'
# Commits to local and remote
# TODO How to merge changes in 'task3' into 'trunk' of SVN by using Git only?
git-workflow() {
# Developer 3 (git) creates working copy, branch:
git svn clone -s file://"$DIR"/svnrepos/project "$DIR"/developer_git1

cd "$DIR"/developer_git1

git svn -m "Create a branch for task 3" branch task3 # The branch will be created on SVN

git branch task3 remotes/origin/task3 

git checkout task3

sed -i -r 's/(.*)/\1 Germany/g' readme.txt

git add -u

git commit -m "Change from developer_git1" # Commit in local Git branch

git svn dcommit # Commit to the corresponding SVN branch

}
```

But I cannot figure out how can I merge the changes in local Git branch `task3` into the `trunk` of SVN.

I tried the following:

```
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git branch -a
  master
* task3
  remotes/origin/task1
  remotes/origin/task2
  remotes/origin/task3
  remotes/origin/trunk
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git show-ref
7c4844a091dd649a7ffd15a3dac07da927fca426 refs/heads/master
2e0964804ba1f3f84baaba8ade0934899ea2a69d refs/heads/task3
6e42f27d10ca25a0189b94d8dc1ada96a38f494b refs/remotes/origin/task1
7992320699f10f77062c2c7fa9c78edeec2ce01b refs/remotes/origin/task2
2e0964804ba1f3f84baaba8ade0934899ea2a69d refs/remotes/origin/task3
7c4844a091dd649a7ffd15a3dac07da927fca426 refs/remotes/origin/trunk
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git merge task3 
Updating 7c4844a..2e09648
Fast-forward
 readme.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git show-ref
2e0964804ba1f3f84baaba8ade0934899ea2a69d refs/heads/master
2e0964804ba1f3f84baaba8ade0934899ea2a69d refs/heads/task3
6e42f27d10ca25a0189b94d8dc1ada96a38f494b refs/remotes/origin/task1
7992320699f10f77062c2c7fa9c78edeec2ce01b refs/remotes/origin/task2
2e0964804ba1f3f84baaba8ade0934899ea2a69d refs/remotes/origin/task3
7c4844a091dd649a7ffd15a3dac07da927fca426 refs/remotes/origin/trunk
/tmp/svn-experiments/developer_git1$ git svn dcommit
Committing to file:///tmp/svn-experiments/svnrepos/project/branches/task3 ...
```

How do I force `master` to point to `trunk` and commit there?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a case where someone uses git to push to SVN. You should use tortoiseSVN rather than git if you are working with the SVN workflow. See https://tortoisesvn.net/.